# SFTP: chroot jail with different ownership

Tags: linux, sftp, chroot

SFTP directory - `/qon/app/report`

Ownership of the `/qon/app` directory is `tom:qcc`

I cannot change the ownership to `root:root` as there are a lot of applications that depend on it.
Is it possible to implement chroot jail for a user without changing the ownership to `root:root` for `/qon/app`?

I want to restrict the user only to the sftp directory but cannot change the permissions of the previous directory to `root:root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible with OpenSSH for security reasons, but you might be able to achieve the same with other sftp servers.